# Including null values in unpivoted column

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

Consider the following table:

```
id  title   genre1  genre2  genre3  genre4  genre5
1   Movie1  Thriller    Crime   NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Movie2  Fantasy NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   Movie3  Political   Philosophical   Historical  NULL    NULL
4   Movie4  Science Fiction NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

When I unpivot genre1, genre2, ... the NULL values are removed, so that, for example, the rows for Movie1 would be:

```
id title  genre     original_column
1  Movie1 Thriller  genre1
1  Movie1 Crime     genre2
```

Is there a way to include NULL values, for example:

```
id title  genre     original_column
1  Movie1 Thriller  genre1
1  Movie1 Crime     genre2
1  Movie1 NULL      genre3
1  Movie1 NULL      genre4
1  Movie1 NULL      genre5
```

I can `SELECT ISNULL(genre1, '*'), ISNULL(genre2, '*') ...`, but suppose I want the values to appear as NULL? Is there a better way than:

```
WITH 
-- SELECT that unpivots table
AS unpivoted
SELECT unpivoted.id, 
  unpivoted.title, 
  ,CASE unpivoted.genre WHEN '*' THEN NULL ELSE unpivoted.genre END 
  ,unpivoted.original_transaction
FROM unpivoted
```

Also, I notice that the query that returns the source data to be unpivoted MUST have an alias. For example:

```
SELECT ... FROM
  -- *must* give it an alias or it's a syntax error
  (SELECT ... FROM) AS source 
  UNPIVOT(genre for original_column IN (genre1,genre2, genre3,genre4,genre5))
```

Does anyone know why? I have not found a way to refer to the alias anywhere in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can anyone answer part (2), which was: Does anyone know why the query that returns the source data to be unpivoted MUST have an alias, even though the alias is apparently useless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the unpivot in a cross apply instead to get the result you want.

```
declare @T table
(
  id int,
  title varchar(50),
  genre1 varchar(50),
  genre2 varchar(50),
  genre3 varchar(50),
  genre4 varchar(50),
  genre5 varchar(50)
);

insert into @T values
(1, 'Movie1', 'Thriller', 'Crime',  NULL,  NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Movie2', 'Fantasy', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Movie3', 'Political', 'Philosophical', 'Historical', NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Movie4', 'Science Fiction', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

select T.id,
       T.title,
       G.genre,
       G.original_column
from @T as T
  cross apply (
              select T.genre1, 'genre1' union all
              select T.genre2, 'genre2' union all
              select T.genre3, 'genre3' union all
              select T.genre4, 'genre4' union all
              select T.genre5, 'genre5'
              ) as G(genre, original_column);
```

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later you can use the [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) instead of `union all` as suggested by Vladimir Baranov in a comment.

```
select T.id,
       T.title,
       G.genre,
       G.original_column
from @T as T
  cross apply (values (T.genre1, 'genre1'),
                      (T.genre2, 'genre2'),
                      (T.genre3, 'genre3'),
                      (T.genre4, 'genre4'),
                      (T.genre5, 'genre5')
              ) as G(genre, original_column);
```

Comment: Instead of `UNION ALL` you can also use `VALUES` syntax: `cross apply 
 (
  values 
  (T.genre1,'genre1'), 
  (T.genre2,'genre2'), 
  (T.genre3,'genre3'), 
  (T.genre4,'genre4'), 
  (T.genre5,'genre5')
 ) AS G(genre, original_column)`

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov: Less typing is always good. i don't know how to upvote your comment.